# writing sftp inbound and outbound adapter without xml configuration in spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I need to create a SFTP inbound and outbound adapter using java with no XMl configuration.
The problem, I am facing is I am not able to create a CachingSessionFactory and DefaultSessionFactory with a privatekey as a property. If anyone has tried it earlier. Please help

Answer (score 2):

It is a first sample how to configure it from Java code:

```
InputStream stream = new ClassPathResource("id_rsa").getInputStream();
f.setPrivateKey(new ByteArrayResource(StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(stream)));
```

Another feature from Spring Java & Annotation Configuration looks like this:

```
@Value("com/my/proj/integration/ssl/myKey")
private Resource myKey;
```

And pay attention, please, to the [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) for xml-less configuration. And here is a test class for the [SFTP](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/sftp/SftpTests.java) to get an info how to configure those adapters with Java DSL.

Comment: I have gone through the DSL example of SFTP. The example is with Lambda expression compliant to JDK 1.8 . Can you please give an example of SFTP inbound and outbound DSL using non lambda . Struggling for 3/4 days to write. Thanks for your patient answer in the community

Comment: I'd say it would be better that you spend 10-15 min to understand what is Lambdas in Java 8 and convert all those my samples to inline interface implementations, rather than I'll write the whole code for you.